# CPLEX - adding min in constraints & how to write sum with different values

Tags: optimization, sum, constraints, linear-programming, cplex

I am new to this platform CPLEX which means a beginner of programming.
I'm trying to write the code for CPLEX for below questions.

Question 1.

∑j (X^D(i,j,t) <= min(k^P(i,t),k^A(i,t) for all i, t

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KX1lL.png)

I tried to write the code like something below

```
forall(i in plants,t in years)
    {
      sum(j in products:j!)(X[i,j,t]) <= kP[i,t];
      sum(j in products:j!)(X[i,j,t]) <= kA[i,t];
    }
```

Is this right?
First, how do you write the code (sum of j, without having specific values)

Second, is there a way to express 'min' constraint in CPLEX?

The next question is how do you write the code of sum of four values.

It's the advanced version of the upper question.

cost_t=∑s,i,m,j(c^S(s,i,m,j,t)*X^S(s,i,m,j,t)+∑i,j,t(c(i,j,t)*X(i,j,t)+∑i,r,j,t(c^D(i,r,j,t)*X^D(i,r,j,t)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JlhM.png)

How do you write the sum part with four or three index?

Thank you for your kind answers and you are the bests.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

```
range plants=1..10;
range years=2021..2022;
range products=1..4;

dvar int+ X[plants][products][years];

int kP[i in plants,t in years]=i*t;
int kA[i in plants,t in years]=i*t+2;

dvar float cost;
subject to
{

forall(i in plants,t in years)
    {
      sum(j in products:j!=1)(X[i,j,t]) <= minl(kP[i,t],kA[i,t]);
      
    }
   
   cost==sum(i,i2 in plants,t in years,j in products:i!=j) (X[i][j][t]+X[i2][j][t]);
   
    
  }
```

works fine

minl means minimum of a few values